# Oracle difference between to dates in days without considering time

Tags: oracle, date, extract, ceil, current-time

How to get days count from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP without considering time (hours,minutes,seconds).
for eg. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is `24-JUN-21 00.01.01 AM`
and `EVENT_TIMESTAMP` is `23-JUN-21 07.00.00 PM` then it should return `1` day difference.

Below query returning me `0` days for above values, because time difference is less than 24 hours.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - EVENT_TIMESTAMP)) FROM TABLE;
```

Below query returning me `1` days difference till 7PM and it start showing `2` days difference after 7PM on same date.

```
SELECT CEIL(SYSDATE - CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)) FROM TABLE;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you should just TRUNCate those values:

```
SQL> select   trunc(to_date('24.06.2021 00:01:01', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
  2         - trunc(to_date('23.06.2021 07:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) result
  3  from dual;

    RESULT
----------
         1

SQL>
```

TRUNC will "remove" time component (actually, set it to *midnight*) and you'd subtract only dates. Difference of two DATE datatype values in Oracle represents number of days between them so ... maybe that's what you're looking for.